# How we can publish an app in google developer console site?

Tags: google-chrome, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-developers-console

I have made a web application app through PHP. It is in testing mode right now. Please guide me how we can publish the app successfully in google developer console site.

P.S - I need to publish the app as my token gets expire after few days and I didn't want it to expire for a longer period of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to google developer console for your project

On the consent screen first page  Click the button that says publish app.

[image]